# Where to learn and construct a url for ajax using API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just found a jsfiddle  sample http://jsfiddle.net/Braulio/vDr36/  that uses ajax.

My question is how does one know the url along with other parameters/functions etc.

For example

here the url is

```
var query = "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=soccer&format=json";
```

I tried to look up in Flickr API website. Nothing was mentioned about this site?

Correct me what I am wrong. THanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read the documentation of any API which provide to check all the existing properties ,

for using Flickr API you can see the argument sections

https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

Search it in google as "(any library) API documentation " this will get you enough of information to use

Comment: ok Zan. I am not well versed with this. I dont see "photos_public.gne" anywhere